# How to set another user role for current user?

Tags: wordpress

Have some problem... Maybe somebody knows how to set role for current user in Wordpress.

I tried this code

```
 function uproles()
   {
       $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
       $roles = $current_user->roles;
       if (current_user_can('access1') == true) {$role = "access2";}
       do_action('set_user_role', $current_user->ID, $role, $roles );
    }
```

But it seems it does not work:(

Answer (score 0):

From admin panel Just goto Users > your user and set the user role to what ever you want. If you want to set a default role to all new users, goto Settings>writing there is a field where you can set the default role.